# Using Async to save a FileStream

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I am trying to save a file(BitmapImage) to a certain location, but as soon as I use `async` & `await` I get an error saying the file is in use:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\ ... \image1.jpg' because
>   it is being used by another process.

My coding:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(oldImagePath));
var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { QualityLevel = 17 };
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));

using (var filestream = new FileStream(GetImageLocation(), FileMode.Create))
    await Task.Run(() => encoder.Save(filestream)); //Error here
```

When I use the code *without* the `await`, the code works perfectly fine. I think it might be because another thread might be using it, but can anyone help or explain to me a work around for my issue? Thank you.

Comment: You could encode to a memory stream get the byte array then use `WriteAsync` on the `FileStream` and avoid using `Task.Run` altogether.

Comment: @juharr That sounds interesting, I will try it out thank you.

Comment: @juharr You could also post your solution as an alternative solution for someone else that might need it? I might also use it as with the current selected answer, my images load to slow and my `Image` control loads before the image, so no image shows...(also because of the different threads doing the work).

Comment: Your thread will be blocked during the CPU bound encoding process, but that should be much less time than the IO.  You might also consider not even using `await` depending on where this code is running (if in the UI thread then you'd want to keep it to avoid locking up the UI during the save).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case when you use `Task` with `await` another thread is used to save your `encoder`. But your encoder is also used by your main thread so new thread can't use it.

Change your code a little:

```
await Task.Run(() => 
{ 
    using (var filestream = new FileStream(GetImageLocation(), FileMode.Create))
    {      
         BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(oldImagePath));
         var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { QualityLevel = 17 };
         encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
         encoder.Save(filestream);
    }
}
```

Now you create and save your `encoder` in the same task and it will use only one thread.

Comment: Why not move all of it into the Task.Run call?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should move the code inside the `Task.Run`, because it gets called inside another thread.

Comment: What does this provide, that Roma's answer doesn't?

Comment: we replied at the same moment

Answer (score 4):

You could encode to a `MemoryStream`, get the byte array, use `WriteAsync` on the `FileStream`, and avoid using `Task.Run` altogether.

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(oldImagePath));
var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { QualityLevel = 17 };
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
using (var filestream = new FileStream(GetImageLocation(), FileMode.Create))
{
    encoder.Save(mem);
    var data = mem.ToArray();
    await filestream.WriteAsync(date, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Note that this will block your thread during the encoding and will use more memory.